# Repetition of number up to limit, then loop it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to do this in jQuery:

```
var limit=3;

if input is 1 ==> the output is 1;
if input is 2 ==> the output is 2;
if input is 3 ==> the output is 3;
//after the limit (in this example 3)
if input is 4 ==> the output is 1;
if input is 5 ==> the output is 2;
if input is 6 ==> the output is 3;
//again
if input is 7 ==> the output is 1;
if input is 8 ==> the output is 2;
if input is 9 ==> the output is 3.
...
```

I used do-while loop, but I hope that there is a better (in terms of number of lines) function.

Thanks a lot

Fabio

Comment: zellio and Vijay: thanks a lot!! The modulo operator is the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the modulo operator which returns the remainder of division.

```
var x = val % 3;
```

The only difference is that you'll want to add 3 to the value if it's 0 (as `3 % 3 == 0`)

```
var x = val % 3;
if (val == 0) 
    val = 3;
```

You could make this code more generic / useful by using a function.

```
function looped_number(number, limit) {
    var val = number % limit;
    if (val == 0) 
        val = limit;
    return val;
}
```

You can also make the above code more concise by using the logical `||` operator.

```
function looped_number(number, limit) {
    return number % limit || limit;
}
```

Comment: number % limit || number; will return "Number" in case of number is a multiple of  limit.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
output = input % limit || limit ;
```

Comment: This will return 1 if the input is divisible by the limit rather than returning the limit value.